# I'm trying to count the anagrams using Java

Tags: java

For eg:
String a =abcd;
String b=abcg;

To make it as anagram,we need to delete the elements d from a and g from b..
so,here answer is 2.
I converted this strings to character arrays

I'm trying save the elements which are equal in both the arrays in a nw duplicate array
and want to get the result by subtracting this duplicate length from total length of two arrays...but unable to get the result

code:

int n=arr1.length+arr2.length;

```
    char[] dp=new char[n];
     for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
             if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]) {
             
                dp[i]=arr1[i];
     }
    
}
     }
     System.out.println(n-(dp.length));
```

I also tried to get the result by counting them....which means to count how many elements are matching and to get the result,subtracting it from original length

code:int n=arr1.length+arr2.length;

```
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
             if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]) {
             
            count++;
     }
    
}
     }
     //2 is for two arrays
     System.out.println(n-(2*count));
```

can you please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that you count a pair of letters multiple times. And the time complexity over here is of O(n^2) while it could easily be done in O(n)

Example to show how your logic is wrong: let a = "aaa" and b = "aa"

```
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
             if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]) {
             
            count++;
     }
    
}
     }
     //2 is for two arrays
     System.out.println(n-(2*count));
```

here your code will give count = 6 whereas n = 5 which is not possible.

**O(n) solution:**

Use two integer arrays of size 26, one for each string. Where each value in the array corresponds to an alphabet (a to z). For each occurrence of an alphabet in the string increment the value of the corresponding array value. This way you will be having 2 arrays each having number of occurrences of every alphabet in the corresponding string. Iterate through both the integer array and the absolute difference between both the integer array. That will be the number of characters you have to delete to make the strings anagram.

```
// two arrays two count the occurance of each alphabet.
int c1[] = new int[26];
int c2[] = new int[26];

// initialize the count of each alphabet to 0
for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
    c1[i]=0;
    c2[i]=0;
}

// for occurance of each alphabet in the string increment that alphabets count
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length();i++) {
    c1[arr1[i]-'a']+=1;
}
for(int i=0;i<arr2.length();i++) {
    c2[arr2[i]-'a']+=1;
}
    
// for the strings to be anagram the occurance of each character should be same.
// so number of characters to delete from both the strings is sum of the absolute difference of occurance of each alphabet.

int ans = 0;
for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    ans += java.lang.Math.abs(c1[i]-c2[i])
    
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your first approach, you are printing

```
System.out.println(n-(dp.length));
```

as your result, but the size of dp array is equal to n as,

```
char[] dp=new char[n];
```

That's why you'll always get 0 as result.

Second approach is only acceptable for some cases,like it always gives wrong answer for both the strings having same characters because in that case your count is always greater than n and it results out as negative answer.

*You can better do it in O(n) time by making arrays for both the Strings and store frequency of both the characters in it, and finally return the difference of frequencies of both the arrays. *

**O(n) Solution :**

```
int count1[] = new int[26];  
int count2[] = new int[26]; 

//Store Frequecies of each character of first array
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length() ; i++) 
count1[str1.charAt(i) -'a']++; 
   
//Store Frequecies of each character of first array
for (int i = 0; i < str2.length() ; i++) 
 count2[str2.charAt(i) -'a']++; 

//Return difference in frequencies of both the arrays
int result = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
 result += Math.abs(count1[i] -  count2[i]);
```

Comment: thank you but I'm confusing at" count1[str1.CharAt(i)-'a]++; how does it work...what will be the output?

Comment: Our main purpose is to find out how many characters are different in both the arrays, and that's why we are creating two count arrays so that for each character we are increasing the value at that place .   Now as we know  'b'-'a'=1, 'd'-'a'=3 as the difference in their ascii values,that's why we use [str1.CharAt(i)-'a] to find the position of the character..

Answer (score 0):

The very first problem will be time complexity here. We can do this with another method also. First of all we have to make an array of length 256, as there are a total of 256 characters inclding a-z,A-Z,!,@,#,$,% and all. Then we will run the first string in a for loop and for every character in that string, its frequency will be increased in the array. By doing this we will get to know that how many times each and every character of the string occurs in it.

```
 `int frequency[] = new int [256];

//we will use a for each loop here
      for(char c: a.toCharArray()) {
      int count = (int)c;
            frequency[count]++;  }

//Till here we get to know which and how many characters are there in first string.
//Now we will do the same with second string but instead of making another array, we 
//will use the same array and this time rather than increasing the frequency, we will 
//decrease.

        for(char c: b.toCharArray()) {
                int count = (int)c;
                frequency[index]--;
            }   

//Now if both the strings don't contain same and equal number of char, the difference 
//will be showed in the frequency array.
//In other words if both the strings are anagram,then the value of all char in 
//frequency would be zero.

     int difference = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<frequency.length(); i++){
        if(frequency[i] !=0){
          difference += frequency[i];} 
     }
     System.out.println(difference)
`
```